# Adding a specific property to each json object in an array in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an array of JSON objects and I want to add a particular property to each object present.

For example, the array is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Average":  1.3085,
        "ExtendedStatistics":  {

                               },
        "Maximum":  0,
        "Minimum":  0,
        "SampleCount":  0,
        "Sum":  0,
        "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1496972280000)\/",
        "Unit":  {
                     "Value":  "Percent"
                 }
    },
    {
        "Average":  1.4324999999999999,
        "ExtendedStatistics":  {

                               },
        "Maximum":  0,
        "Minimum":  0,
        "SampleCount":  0,
        "Sum":  0,
        "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1496944680000)\/",
        "Unit":  {
                     "Value":  "Percent"
                 }
    }
]
```

I want to add "source": "CPU" to all objects. How do I go about doing that? I am new to PowerShell and haven't been able to get this done.

Answer (score 10):

You could do the following:

```
$JSON | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source' -Value 'CPU' -PassThru
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

This assumes your JSON input is in a variable named `$JSON`, you'll need to replace this with however you access your JSON content (e.g `Get-Content yourfile.json`).

Once you have the JSON, we use `ConvertFrom-JSON` to convert it to a PowerShell object.

We then use the pipeline to send this to a `ForEach-Object` loop which uses the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add a property to each item in the collection (the current item is represented by `$_`) named 'Source' with a value of 'CPU'. Per the comments from mklement0, it is necessary to use the `-PassThru` switch to send the result back to the pipeline.

Then we pipe that output to ConvertTo-JSON to convert it back.

Answer (score 6):

[Mark Wragg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473048/45375) works well, but you may wonder **why the `Add-Member` cmdlet cannot be piped to *directly*, as opposed to requiring an enclosing `ForEach-Object` call**:

Arguably, **the following *should* work, but in *Windows PowerShell* doesn't**:

```bash
# !! Does NOT work as expected in Windows PowerShell.
# OK in PowerShell (Core) 7+ 
$JSON | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source' -Value 'CPU' -PassThru
```

The idea is that `Add-Member` uses pipeline input directly, and, after modifying each input object, outputs it, thanks to `-PassThru` (by default `Add-Member` produces no output).

The reason that it doesn't work is that **when Windows PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` outputs an *array*, it outputs it *as a single object* rather than sending its elements one by one through the pipeline**, as one would expect.

- In **PowerShell [Core] 7.0**, the **behavior was changed** to align with the usual enumeration-of-elements behavior, and a `-NoEnumerate` switch was added as an opt-in to the old behavior. For the discussion that led to this change, see [GitHub issue #3424](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).

**Workarounds**:

- Use `(...)`, which forces enumeration of the array:

```bash
# Enclosing the ConvertFrom-Json command in (...) forces enumeration.
($JSON | ConvertFrom-Json) | 
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source' -Value 'CPU' -PassThru
```

<sup>Note that, generally, using `(...)` to force collection of a command's entire output in-memory in an array is convenient, but can be problematic with large output sets. As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) points out, however, in *this* case it is fine, because `ConvertFrom-Json` itself constructs the entire output array in memory up front anyway.</sup>

- Alternative: A pass-through call to
  `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` (*Windows* PowerShell) /
  *just* `Write-Output` (PowerShell *Core*), whose sole purpose is to force enumeration of the array elements:

```bash
# Inserting Write-Output [-NoEnumerate] between ConvertFrom-Json and Add-Member
# forces enumeration of the array elements.

# *Windows PowerShell*, as of v5.1:
$JSON | ConvertFrom-Json | Write-Output -NoEnumerate |
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source' -Value 'CPU' -PassThru 

# PowerShell *Core*:
$JSON | ConvertFrom-Json | Write-Output |
  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Source' -Value 'CPU' -PassThru
```

---

#### Optional reading: the quirks of `Write-Output`:

***Windows PowerShell* as of v5.1**:

Due to a *bug*, `Write-Output` *invariably* enumerates single objects that are collections themselves, even when you add `-NoEnumerate`.

Paradoxically, `-NoEnumerate` is actually *needed* in this case - even though we *do* want to enumerate! - so as to prevent `Write-Output` from applying enumeration *twice*: once (invariably) to the input array, and again to the individual array elements (thanks again, PetSerAl); e.g.:

```bash
# !! Unexpectedly returns 4(!): enumerates the outer 2-element array
# !! *and* its elements.
# (In PowerShell *Core*, this yields 2, as expected.)
Write-Output -InputObject (1, 2), (3, 4) | Measure-Object

# BETTER: yields 2, because only the outer 2-element array is enumerated
# (In PowerShell *Core*, this yields 1, as expected.)
Write-Output -NoEnumerate -InputObject (1, 2), (3, 4) | Measure-Object
```

**PowerShell (Core) v6.2.3+**:

The above problem has been fixed - see [GitHub issue #5955](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5955) - which means that - sensibly - you *mustn't* use `-NoEnumerate` if you do want `Write-Output` to enumerate pipeline objects that are themselves collections (and enumeration no longer recurses 1 level).